# PHP. Не получается прочитать SOAP ответ сервера. MTOM?

Tags: php, soap

Есть запрос к серверу вебсервисов по SOAP. Все на первый взгляд обычно - конверт с некими данными. Через SoapUI запросы выполняются, ответы приходят. Но как только дело доходит до запросов и обработки ответов через PHP, то тут начинаются проблемы. Нативный PHP SoapClient не может прочитать ответ, он попросту зависает. Никак не удается заставить работать. Были попытки имитировать SOAP запросы через cURL\Guzzle, но увы результат такой же.

Ниже скрины. Есть подозрение, что это [MTOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism), но я не уверен.

Прошу, если у кого-то есть опыт или кто-то знает, в чем может быть проблема, подсказать с решением.

Запрос
[image http://clip2net.com/clip/m258506/79a1d-clip-11kb.png](http://clip2net.com/clip/m258506/79a1d-clip-11kb.png)
[image http://clip2net.com/clip/m258506/f28cd-clip-13kb.png](http://clip2net.com/clip/m258506/f28cd-clip-13kb.png)

И ответ. Обратите внимание на выделенную красным часть
[image http://clip2net.com/clip/m258506/c2b80-clip-16kb.png](http://clip2net.com/clip/m258506/c2b80-clip-16kb.png)
[image http://clip2net.com/clip/m258506/1c91d-clip-30kb.png](http://clip2net.com/clip/m258506/1c91d-clip-30kb.png)

Что это за фрагменты? Как заставить SoapClient нормально работать?